# include closing tag of a jsx element in another element

Tags: reactjs

I want to iterate over cells and build an table, grid. so i need to close row tag based on condition.

`if (index%col == 0 && index/col > i++) board.push( </div> )`
     `if (index%col == 0) rowJSX = board.push(<div className="Board-row">)`

Comment: JSX doesn't work like that. You can include children if you like (conditionally), or even look at CSS Grid if you want a more modern approach

Comment: An unclosed tag is invalid syntax,  you're not building a string that will be parsed by an HTML parser later on the client.

Comment: CSS grid works with a flat children structure anyway, have you tried to just specify `grid-template-columns` without any nested JSX, e.g. `<div style={{gridTemplateColumns: \`repeat(${col}, 1fr)\`...` on the parent?

Comment: @Aprillion how is this? could u send a tutorial? more info plz

Comment: @JuanMendes I know this man, i am just wonder how is the efficient way to do nested element like table or div in div

Comment: @Aprillion i need some info about ur info! i now read grid, i will that style in grid container to get auto row or column created for my columns row, but what do you mean by Without nested!?

Comment: flat list of children like in  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout#Basic_example

Comment: @Aprillion i dont understand the part of nested jsx! at last i should nest jsx together! explain a little how i dont need nested jsx! you mean only use simple div as my jsx child doesnt mean nested?

Answer (score 3):

JSX is not about strings concatenation. HTML tag here is transformed into `React.createElement`so you just cannot close tag conditionally like, say, you cannot close block conditionally `if(...) { } }`

Instead just collect your data into array like

```
row.push({ className: ..., value: });
```

And later iterate over to create JSX elements:

```
row.map(item => <td className={item.className}>{item.value}</td>)
```

[upd] and work with rows in the same way:

```
rows.map(row => (<tr>
    {row.map(item => <td className={item.className}>{item.value}</td>)}
</tr>))
```

Comment: I know that! But how close the tr tag to each row in iter! i mean the efficient way

Comment: Oh good to go like this , map all over. Thanks but is there any better way